# How can I line up alerts and order placement?

Tags: alert, pine-script, binance

I have coded a strategy in Pinescript on TradingView and created an alert when strategy.entry meets its conditions, my question now is, sometimes the alert triggers on the strategy.entry while the strategy.entry doesn't execute an order.

For example, i get an alert from the code below which means it has triggered, but it doesn't actually place a buy order. How is it possible I get an alert, (which transfers to binance) while the strategy itself doesn't actually execute anything?

`strategy.entry("Buy", long=true, when = crossover(SmaSrc, Sma), comment = "c776154f_ENTER-LONG_BINANCE_ADA/EUR_c776154f-Jan-Pieter_30M")`

Many thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen, afawk. Would be better to contact TV support for this.